# Cannot access array inside of map function to return props to different component

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching data from an API. I am building an array of 5 objects using the API call. What I am trying to do is iterate over the array, use the data inside each array index to build a component and pass along the props to another component.

I've tried accessing the element the same way I normally would by doing:
img={pokemon.name} but it keeps returning undefined. When I type in
console.log(pokemon) I get the individual pokemon stored within the array of objects.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pokecard from "./Pokecard";

async function getPokemon() {
  const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1;
  const pokeRes = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}/`);
  const pokemonJSON = await pokeRes.json();
  return pokemonJSON;
}

function buildPokemon() {
  let pokemonArr = [];
  let builtPokemon = {};

  getPokemon()
    .then(data => {
      builtPokemon.name = data.forms[0].name;
      builtPokemon.exp = data.base_experience;
      builtPokemon.img = data.sprites.front_default;
      builtPokemon.type = data.types[0].type.name;

      pokemonArr.push(builtPokemon);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  return pokemonArr;
}

class Pokedex extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pokemonArr: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const pokemonArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      pokemonArr.push(buildPokemon());
    }
    this.setState({ pokemonArr });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pokemonArr);
    return (
      <div className="Pokedex">
        {this.state.pokemonArr.map(pokemon => console.log(pokemon))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pokedex;
```

What should happen is that when I map the pokemonArr I want to create 5 separate pokemon by doing
`this.state.pokemonArr.map(pokemon => <Pokecard name={pokemon.name}` but I keep getting undefined whenever I check this.props in the Pokecard component.

I think my buildPokemon() function is working because when I call it in the componentDidMount() and then I console.log `this.state.pokemonArr` in the render() function, I actually get an array returned with 5 different pokemon with the proper fields filled out.

And also when I map out this.state.pokemonArr.map(pokemon => clg(pokemon)), it actually displays each individual pokemon. When I pass the pokemon item into a component like this
`<Pokecard name={pokemon}/>`, I see all the pokemon data.
when I type `<Pokecard name={pokemon.name} I get undefined`

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` executes after first render, initially your state is `pokemonArr: []` (whch is empty) so you are getting an error. You need to conditionally render like,

```
{this.state.pokemonArr.length > 0 && this.state.pokemonArr.map(pokemon => console.log(pokemon))}
```

---

**Side Note:**

In `buildPokemon` function you are returning an `array`, and again in `componentDidMount` you are storing it in `array` which creates `array of array's`, you just need to return `object` from `buildPokemon` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach but the main one is that `getPokemon()` is asynchronous.

Return the `getPokemon()` promise from `buildPokemon()` and return the object from it's `then()`

In your `for()` loop create an array of these promises and use `Promise.all()` to set state once they have all resolved

```
function buildPokemon() {

  let builtPokemon = {};
  // return the promise
  return getPokemon()
    .then(data => {
      builtPokemon.name = data.forms[0].name;
      builtPokemon.exp = data.base_experience;
      builtPokemon.img = data.sprites.front_default;
      builtPokemon.type = data.types[0].type.name;
      // return the object
      return builtPokemon
    });
}


componentDidMount() {
  const pokemonPromises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pokemonPromises.push(buildPokemon());
  }
  Promise.all(pokemonPromises).then(pokemonArr => this.setState({ pokemonArr }));    
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. This worked. I have a question if you don't mind. If I'm trying to store an array of asynchronous data, I should send back the object as a promise, then call it in my loop and store each promise in an array of promises, and then Promise.all and update the state? Sorry if what I said was confusing. Long-story short I need to be more careful around asynchronous data.

Comment: Short answer is you were returning the array before it got populated. And on top of that you were creating an array of arrays. I left that last part out of my explanation to minimize confusion.

Comment: So now you have an array of promises with each promise returning a single object. Promise.all() returns an array of those objects once resolved

Comment: Thank you again charlie, your explanation was great too. I see exactly what I was doing wrong now. You rock dude.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly how the Promise should be resolved.

The data isn't available right away so the state (`pokemonArr`) should only be set once data is available.

Here's the refactored component:

```
class Pokedex extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pokemonArr: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.getPokemon()
        .then((pokemon) => this.buildPokemon(pokemon));
    }
  }
  async getPokemon() {
    const randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1;
    const pokeRes = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${randomID}/`);

    return pokeRes.json();
  }
  setPokemon(pokemon) {
    this.setState({
      pokemonArr: [
        ...this.state.pokemonArr, pokemon
      ],
    });
  }
  buildPokemon(data) {
    let builtPokemon = {};

    builtPokemon.name = data.forms[0].name;
    builtPokemon.exp = data.base_experience;
    builtPokemon.img = data.sprites.front_default;
    builtPokemon.type = data.types[0].type.name;

    this.setPokemon(builtPokemon);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Pokedex">
        {this.state.pokemonArr.map(pokemon => console.log(pokemon))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```